# Does Eclipse have a plugin for code clips like in Coda?

Tags: eclipse, ide, editor, eclipse-plugin, coda

There is a very useful "Clips" feature in Coda, does Eclipse have such feature?

What it does is pretty simple, you save a code clip once, which you use very often and assign it a shortcut and when you want to re-use you type the shortcut and it automatically pastes it and sets the caret at the defined position.

e.g. when I type `4dom` and press `TAB` it types this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    //puts cursor here
});
```

so, how do you do this in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse they are called Templates. You can find this in Window->Preferences then JavaScript/Editor/Templates.

It will allow you to create or edit.

Comment: Thanks but i couldn't find the way how to add a new template and how to use them, is it correct where i landed http://drp.ly/QSF5N ?

Answer (score 1):

Similar function in Eclipse is called Snippets.
Find it by doing this:
click on Window > Show View > Other > General > Snippets